# Python version to use with ROS kinetic

Tags: gazebo7, ros-kinetic, python3, python2.7, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which python interpreter version is most advisable to use with ROS kinetic and gazebo 7 simulator?
As I read to set up ros to work with python 3 requires a extra effort.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270569/python-version-to-use-with-ros-kinetic/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS kinetic targets Python2.7 (It does recommends compatibility with python 3 but doesn't require it).
Gazebo doesn't have a Python interface AFAIK.

You can find more details about what version of languages and dependencies a specific ROS distribution targets on [REP3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021).

Hope this helps

Edit: "As I read to set up ros to work with python 3 requires a extra effort." indeed python3 not being officially supported, none of the packages are tested with python3, thus there is no list of known compatibility problems and the potential of breakage is pretty high. So I'd recommend python2.7 and if you write python code to write it in a way that it can run with both versions

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2017-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
See also a number of previous questions about this: #q237613 and #q262551 fi.